# Is there a way to stop receiving an exception error when dereferencing a nullptr while destroying a linked list?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pointers, linked-list

I'm required to destroy an array (populated and accessed via hashing) in which multiple pointers point to nullptr. I copied the exact example for destroying a linked list from my textbook, but I still get a runtime exception when I attempt to deallocate the memory used for the Node objects.

**Can I simply tell Visual Studios to ignore nullptr dereferencing exceptions during execution or is there a proper way of deallocating such a linked list that it isn't being shown in the book?**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsA2Q.jpg)

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <fstream>

class Manager {
    struct Node {
        int ID, type, capacity, DOB;
        std::string Name;
        Node* next = 0;

        Node(int ID, int type, std::string Name, int DOB, int capacity) :
            ID(ID),
            type(type),
            Name(Name),
            DOB(DOB),
            capacity(capacity)
        {}
    };

    std::array<Node*, 10> head;

    public:
        Manager();
        int h(int);
        void add(int, int, std::string, int, int);
        void print(int);
        void printAll();
        void deleteOne(int);
        ~Manager();
};
```

```cpp
#include "Manager.h"
Manager::Manager() {
    head.fill(0);
    std::fstream records;
    records.open("shipRecords.txt", std::ios::in);
    if (records.is_open()) {
        while (!records.eof()) {
            int ID, type, DOB, capacity;
            std::string Name;
            records >> ID >> type >> Name >> capacity >> DOB;
            add(ID, type, Name, capacity, DOB);
        }
        std::cout << "RECORDS INITIALIZED" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "FILE NOT OPEN" << std::endl;
    }
}

Manager::~Manager() {
    for (int i = 0; i < head.size(); i++) {
        Node* ptr = head[i];
        Node* next = ptr;
        while (ptr) {
            next = ptr->next;
            delete ptr;
            ptr = next->next;
        }
    }
}
```

**I do not experience the same issue when dereferencing nullptrs in the following functions.**

```cpp
void Manager::print(int ID) {
    Node* ptr = head[h(ID)];
    if (ptr) {
        while (ptr->ID != ID && ptr)
            ptr = ptr->next;

        if (!ptr)
            std::cout << "SHIP DOES NOT EXIST" << std::endl;

        std::cout << ptr->ID
            << " " << ptr->type
            << " " << ptr->Name
            << " " << ptr->DOB
            << " " << ptr->capacity
            << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "SHIP DOES NOT EXIST" << std::endl;
    }
}

void Manager::printAll() {
    int items = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < head.size(); i++) {
        Node* ptr = head[i];
        while (ptr) {
            items++;
            std::cout << ptr->ID
                << " " << ptr->type
                << " " << ptr->Name
                << " " << ptr->DOB
                << " " << ptr->capacity
                << std::endl;
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }

        if (items == 0 && i == head.size() - 1)
            std::cout << "NO SHIPS IN THE LIST" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't de-reference nullpointers. It's not a necessary step in the destruction of a linked list to de-reference anything. Is Manager the linked list? The fact that I have to ask points to bad design. And are you trying to make a linked list or an array list?

Comment: In the `print` function, after the `if (!ptr) std::cout << "SHIP DOES NOT EXIST" << std::endl;` you should exit the function.

Comment: @sweenish For the assignment, we're supposed to create an array of pointers to Nodes (Ship objects). We populate this array using the hash function ID%10. It's supposed to teach us about collision and chaining.

Comment: Then it doesn't sound like you're working with a linked list at all.

Comment: *"multiple pointers point to nullptr"* -- I think you mean "multiple pointers are null". (What you wrote would mean that you have a pointer to `std::nullptr_t`, as in `std::nullptr_t * ptr`, and that **the thing pointed to**, `*ptr`, is `nullptr`. What I wrote would describe a pointer to whatever, for example `Node* ptr`, that has **itself** been assigned a null pointer value, such as `nullptr`.)

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to stop receiving an exception error when dereferencing a nullptr while destroying a linked list?

No, dereferencing a `nullptr` makes your program have undefined behavior. Correct your code so it never tries dereferencing `nullptr`s.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is right here:

```
while (ptr) {
    next = ptr->next;
    delete ptr;
    ptr = next->next;
}
```

You're saying, if I know `ptr` is valid, grab whatever it points to as its `next` and store it in the variable `next` (not a great name imo). Then deallocate `ptr`. And finally, **assign the pointer that `ptr`'s `next` was pointing to.**

But you have no guarantee that `next` is a good (non-null) pointer!

This looks like a typo that should probably be:

```
while (ptr) {
    next = ptr->next;
    delete ptr;
    ptr = next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method looks fishy:

```
Manager::~Manager() {
    for (int i = 0; i < head.size(); i++) {
        Node* ptr = head[i];
        Node* next = ptr;
        while (ptr) {
            next = ptr->next;
            delete ptr;
            ptr = next->next;
        }
    }
}
```

You're setting `next` to `ptr->next`. That's fine. You're deleting `ptr`, which you already null-checked.

But then you set `ptr = next->next`. And you really only want to set it to `next`. I bet this is where your error is.